# Google maps api v3, "Object #<Object> has no method 'setValues" error

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Trying to attach map from tutorial "https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map#the_basic_html_page", into simple page, but getting error "Object # has no method 'setValues" in browser console. My code is exact the same as in tutorial, only id is different.

```
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function Initialize() {
            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.8103, 23.8584),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', Initialize);
    </script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Can somebody help me to figure out, why this isn't working for me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You forgot `new`:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks, my bad missing this one.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a copy of the code in that tutorial. Your removed the "new" before the google.maps.Map constructor.

```
 var map = google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
```

In the tutorial is:

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
```